# TypeError: Cannot read property 'user' of undefined. I dont know what to do

Tags: discord.js

```
static description = 'Get information on a mentioned user.';

static usage = '<@user|id>';

static names = ['userinfo', 'ui'];

static userPerms = [];

static botPerms = [];

async execute(client, message) {
    var permissions = [];
var acknowledgements = 'None';
  const args = this.message.content.trim().split(/ +/g);
  var user = this.message.mentions.users.first() || this.message.author;

const member = this.message.mentions.members.first() || this.message.guild.members.cache.get(args[0]) || this.message.member;
const randomColor = "#000000".replace(/0/g, function () { return (~~(Math.random() * 16)).toString(16); }); 

if(this.message.member.hasPermission("KICK_MEMBERS")){
    permissions.push("Kick Members");
}

if(this.message.member.hasPermission("BAN_MEMBERS")){
    permissions.push("Ban Members");
}

if(this.message.member.hasPermission("ADMINISTRATOR")){
    permissions.push("Administrator");
}

if(this.message.member.hasPermission("MANAGE_MESSAGES")){
    permissions.push("Manage Messages");
}

if(this.message.member.hasPermission("MANAGE_CHANNELS")){
    permissions.push("Manage Channels");
}

if(this.message.member.hasPermission("MENTION_EVERYONE")){
    permissions.push("Mention Everyone");
}

if(this.message.member.hasPermission("MANAGE_NICKNAMES")){
    permissions.push("Manage Nicknames");
}

if(this.message.member.hasPermission("MANAGE_ROLES")){
    permissions.push("Manage Roles");
}

if(this.message.member.hasPermission("MANAGE_WEBHOOKS")){
    permissions.push("Manage Webhooks");
}

if(this.message.member.hasPermission("MANAGE_EMOJIS")){
   permissions.push("Manage Emojis");
}

if(!permissions.length == 0){
    permissions.push("No Key Permissions Found");
}

if(this.member.user.id == message.guild.ownerID){
    acknowledgements = 'Server Owner';
}

const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setDescription(`<@${member.user.id}>`)
    .setAuthor(`${member.user.tag}`, member.user.displayAvatarURL)
    .setColor(randomColor)
    .setFooter(`ID: ${message.author.id}`)
    .setThumbnail(member.user.displayAvatarURL)
    .setTimestamp()
    .addField("Status",`${status[member.user.presence.status]}`, true)
    .addField('Joined at: ',`${moment(member.joinedAt).format("dddd, MMMM Do YYYY, HH:mm:ss")}`, true)
    .addField("Created at: ",`${moment(message.author.createdAt).format("dddd, MMMM Do YYYY, HH:mm:ss")}`, true)
    .addField("Permissions: ", `${permissions.join(', ')}`, true)
    .addField(`Roles [${member.roles.cache.filter(r => r.id !== message.guild.id).map(roles => `\`${roles.name}\``).length}]`,`${member.roles.cache.filter(r => r.id !== message.guild.id).map(roles => `<@&${roles.id }>`).join(" **|** ") || "No Roles"}`, true)
    .addField("Acknowledgements: ", `${acknowledgements}`, true);
    
this.message.channel.send({embed});
}
```

}

**I have tried to define user but it's not working. error:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'user' of undefined.
Whenever i used ,userinfo it's not responding anything. I don't know why this happend, but if you find any other error in the code, can you help me fix it too? Thank you.
but that didn't do anything to help.

What am i missing here?**

Answer (score 0):

this.member.user.id

Should be

member.user.id

Look for “something”.user for errors like that. Then figure out why the something is undefined.